# SOAP and need for Java serialVersionUID

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, cxf

Serialization is a process of transforming a object definition into a persistent format (where the format is platform specific). Objects transferred across network  (RMI, EJBs) need to be serializable. SOAP requests are xml based, and JAXB is used to marshall and unmarshall the objects <---> xml. I am prompted by the code-quality plugins to add a SerialVersionUID. Is this required? Do CXF/JAXB internally need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB does not need it, as far as I know. You get this warning because your classes implement `Serializable`, but JAXB doesn't require your classes to be `Serializable`.

If there's no other reason why your classes need to be `Serializable`, you could just change them so that they don't implement `Serializable`.

Your classes only need to implement `Serializable` if you want to be able to serialize/deserialize them using Java's default serialization mechanism (which is used by, for example, RMI).

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention in the JAXB documentation of the need of explicitly adding a SerialVersionUID.

SerialVersionUID is a version number held by each Serializable class, which is used on deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object maintain compatibility as far as serialization is concerned about the classes that are loaded.

It shouldn't be required because the compiler is going to generate a SerialVersionUID by himself so you don't have worry.

The calculation is very sensible to class details so two different compilers can calculate a different SerialVersionUID and in this case a InvalidClassException could be thrown by the JVN during the deserialization process. In this case you should add the SerialVersionUID by your own. You must change the SerialVersionUID every time you modify your class to avoid de/serialization problems (that's because it is preferred not specifying the SerialVersionUID if you are always using the same compiler).

Do not be misled by what your IDE says, that's a decision of your choice based on project development requirements.